# The given Json object value cannot be transformed to a String

Tags: java, spring

I try to put an Armor object to the Equipment object and store it in a database as JSONB format in Hero entity.
There are some entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = Armor.class, name = "armor"),
})
public abstract class Item {

  @Id
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private int count;

  public Item() {

  }
}

@Entity
@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(name = "pgsql_enum", typeClass = PostgreSQLEnumType.class)
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Armor extends Item implements Serializable {

  private int armorStat;

  @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
  @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
  private ArmorType armorType;

  private String description;

  public Armor() {

  }

  public Armor(Integer id, String name, int count, int armorStat,
      ArmorType armorType, String description) {
    super(id, name, count);
    this.armorStat = armorStat;
    this.armorType = armorType;
    this.description = description;
  }
}

@Entity
@Data
public class Hero {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name = "";

  private int fame = 0;

  private int gold = 0;

  private int tiredness = 100;

  private int hp = 10;

  private int damage = 1;

  private int defense = 1;

  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private Equipment equipment;

  @Type(type = "jsonb")
  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private Inventory inventory;

  private String kingdom;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
  private User user;

  public Hero() {
    this.equipment = new Equipment();
    this.inventory = new Inventory();
  }
}

@Data
public class Equipment implements Serializable {

  private Armor helmet;

  private Armor chestplate;

  private Armor gloves;

  private Armor boots;

}
```

And when I try to set equipment and save it to the database it throws the exception like this:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given JSON object value: Equipment(helmet=Item(id=1, name=Leather helmet, count=1), chestplate=null, gloves=null, boots=null) cannot be transformed to a String
```

Service layer code:

```
Hero hero = user.getHero();
Equipment equipment = hero.getEquipment();
Armor armor = armorRepository.getOne(dataParser.getItemId(user.getAttributes().getExecutable()));
equipment.setHelmet(armor);
userService.save(user);
```

I don't know how to fix this. Please give me some advice on how to solve the problem.

Comment: why Equipment doesn't have `@Entity`?

Comment: Because I don't want to store it in the database. Just put it as JSONB in table Hero